# Getting "org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: Invalid use of argument matchers" inconsistently

Tags: java-8, mockito, junit4

A fellow developer wrote a test code that uses mockito verify

```
verify(spyService, times(1)).register("ios", any());
```

Funny thing is that this code executes fine in their local machine, and in jenkins build environment. Code went to production. But the code failed in my local with following

```
Caused by: org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
4 matchers expected, 1 recorded:
-> at com.tile.services.rest.service.insurance.InsuranceCoverageServiceTest.testNonPartnerTilesWithoutTosAcceptance(InsuranceCoverageServiceTest.java:163)

This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
    someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
    //correct:
    someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

Given that the project is well structured via gradle, the junit version is same everywhere.
Do you know what may be causing this inconsistency ?

Comment: Are you running the same exact same version of Java locally as the other developer? IDE not overriding anything?

Answer (score 1):

Did you already use this?

```
verify(spyService, times(1)).register(eq("ios"), any());
```

In your line you are using a specific value `"ios"` and a matcher `any()`and we cannot use both at the same time.
keep it strong